# How can i use Datatables for Php While loop

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, datatables

How can i show Select statement results in the Data-table in PHP. I have used the following code to display record from Mysql table but not working.

I have tried this but no luck

Select Statement

```
$sql = "SELECT demand.itemid,demand.qty, MIITEM.descr,MIITEM.descr,supplier.suplId,supplier.suplProdCode,supplier.itemId,MIILOC.qStk,MIILOC.qWIP,MIILOC.qRes, MIILOC.qOrd
FROM MIITEM
LEFT JOIN demand
ON MIITEM.itemId=demand.itemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier
ON MIITEM.itemId = supplier.itemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN MIILOC
ON MIITEM.itemId = MIILOC.itemId
WHERE MIITEM.itemId=demand.itemId AND supplier.itemId=demand.itemId";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Displaying Records

```
echo"<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <thead>
      <tr style='background:#ccc;'>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:50px; padding:7px'>ID</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:250px; padding:7px'>Description</th>

<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Supplier#</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:200px; padding:7px'>Supplier </th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>ON WO</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Stock</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>WIP</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Reserve</th>
<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>On Order</th>

</tr>   </thead></table>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo"<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody>
<tr>
 <th STYLE='WIDTH:50px; padding:7px'>"; echo$row["itemid"];echo"</th>
 <th STYLE='WIDTH:250px; padding:7px'>"; echo$row["descr"];echo"</th>
 <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>"; echo$row["suplId"];echo"</th>
 <th STYLE='WIDTH:200px; padding:7px'>"; echo$row["suplProdCode"];echo"    </th>";
echo"<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>";echo$row["qty"];echo"</th>";
echo"<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>";echo$row["qStk"];echo"</th>";
echo"<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>";echo$row["qWIP"];echo"</th>";

echo"<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>";echo$row["qRes"];echo"</th>";

echo"<th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>";echo$row["qOrd"];echo"</th>";


echo"</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Here is the Javascript code and the CSS file from `CDN` but nothing is changing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        select: true
    } );
} );

  </script>
```

Comment: Where is your query? do have execute query in php myadmin?

Comment: @paranoid I added the Query at the beginning of my question

Comment: copy this code in php myadmin and do you have result?

Comment: @paranoid yes it gave me the right result  in php myadmin

Comment: Is anything being displayed correctly or at all?

Comment: Your table isn't formatted properly. Datatables will not work on bad tables. You have th in your tbody and a closing table tag at the end of your thead and an opening table at the start of your tbody. Thats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
<?php
//you dont need where condition Left join already filter data over all of your tables demand,supplier, MIILOC
$sql = "SELECT demand.itemid,demand.qty, MIITEM.descr,MIITEM.descr,supplier.suplId,supplier.suplProdCode,supplier.itemId,MIILOC.qStk,MIILOC.qWIP,MIILOC.qRes, MIILOC.qOrd
FROM MIITEM
LEFT JOIN demand
ON MIITEM.itemId=demand.itemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier
ON MIITEM.itemId = supplier.itemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN MIILOC
ON MIITEM.itemId = MIILOC.itemId";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
 printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
 die;
}

$table = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
<thead>
  <tr style='background:#ccc;'>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:50px; padding:7px'>ID</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:250px; padding:7px'>Description</th>

    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Supplier#</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:200px; padding:7px'>Supplier </th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>ON WO</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Stock</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>WIP</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>Reserve</th>
    <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>On Order</th>
</tr>   </thead>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $table .= "<tbody>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $table .= "
      <tr>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:50px; padding:7px'>{$row["itemid"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:250px; padding:7px'>{$row["descr"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["suplId"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:200px; padding:7px'>{$row["suplProdCode"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["qty"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["qStk"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["qWIP"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["qRes"]}</th>
        <th STYLE='WIDTH:100px; padding:7px'>{$row["qOrd"]}</th>
    </tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody>"
}
$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            select: true
        } );
    } );

</script>
```

Comment: I've answered as well ;-) though I wrapped the whole table printing in the `if` and also changed the `th` in the body to `td`. Nice approach though, the adding to a string variable and then doing one `echo` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of habit now.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup was very odd, it looked like you were inserting duplicate tables, with the same ID, for each `$row`. Did anything go into the UI at all? It's always worthwhile to check both the source of the page and also the validity of the markup using an online HTML Validity checker. From what I understand of your needs I've created [this snippet](https://snipt.net/annoyingmouse/php-table/):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "
        <style>
            th, td {
                width: 100px;
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .fifty {
                width: 50px;
            }
            .twohundred {
                width: 200px;
            }
            .twohundredfifty {
                width: 250px;
            }
        </style>
        <table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
            <thead>
                <tr style='background:#ccc;'>
                    <th class='fifty'>ID</th>
                    <th class='twohundredfifty'>Description</th>
                    <th>Supplier#</th>
                    <th class='twohundred'>Supplier </th>
                    <th>ON WO</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>WIP</th>
                    <th>Reserve</th>
                    <th>On Order</th>
                </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    ";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "    <td class='fifty'>".$row["itemid"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td class='twohundredfifty'>".$row["descr"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["suplId"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td class='twohundred'>".$row["suplProdCode"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["qty"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["qStk"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["qWIP"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["qRes"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$row["qOrd"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "
            </tbody>
        </table>
    ";
}
```

It's also always a really good idea to check your code using indents so that you can ensure that the flow of the markup is correct.

Hope that helps.